# Rspec undefined method 'describe'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to go through the tutorial and I have a feeling it's something that has to do with the rspec. The goal is to make each test pass. Here's the website where I could be doing the tutorial but I prefer to do it on my own mac book.

http://testfirst.org/live

https://web.archive.org/web/20140328135623/http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby

I'm on the very first one and I everytime I run

```
$ruby hello_spec.rb
```

I get this error.

```
hello_spec.rb:118:in `<main>': undefined method `describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

rspec (3.1.0, 2.99.0, 2.14.1)

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]

```
require_relative "hello"
describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    hello.should == "Hello!"
  end
end

describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    greet("Alice").should == "Hello, Alice!"
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    greet("Bob").should == "Hello, Bob!"
  end
end
```

please help!

Comment: You need to show us the code you are running. Have you installed `rspec` and are you requiring it in that file? it is not installed by default

Comment: Please give the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code :

```
# hello.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def greet(name)
  "Hello, #{name}!"
end

def hello
  "Hello!"
end

#hello_spec.rb
require_relative "../hello.rb"

describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    expect(hello).to eq "Hello!"
  end
end

describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    expect(greet("Alice")).to eq("Hello, Alice!")
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    expect(greet("Bob")).to eq("Hello, Bob!")
  end
end
```

Now I ran using `ruby` and `rspec` command :

```
[arup@Ruby]$ rspec spec/test_spec.rb
...

Finished in 0.00153 seconds (files took 0.12845 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby spec/test_spec.rb
spec/test_spec.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
[arup@Ruby]$
```

It means, with this set up, you need to run the file using `rspec` command. But, if you want to use, `ruby` command, then need to set up your file as below :

```
require_relative "../hello.rb"
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    expect(hello).to eq "Hello!"
  end
end

RSpec.describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    expect(greet("Alice")).to eq("Hello, Alice!")
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    expect(greet("Bob")).to eq("Hello, Bob!")
  end
end
```

Then run :

```
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby spec/test_spec.rb
...

Finished in 0.00166 seconds (files took 0.15608 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
[arup@Ruby]$
```

[Run with `ruby` command](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/command-line/run-with-ruby-command)

> You can use the ruby command to run specs. You just need to `require
>   rspec/autorun`.Generally speaking, you're better off using the rspec command, which avoids the complexity of `rspec/autorun` (e.g. no `at_exit` hook needed!), but some tools only work with the `ruby` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rspec hello_spec.rb`. You should use rspec command, not ruby. See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line for more details.

Comment: You could use also [`ruby`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/command-line/run-with-ruby-command) command too, but with some extra work. The problem is some where else it seems.